# Вращение изображения через CSS3

Tags: html5, css3, вёрстка

Нужно из этой картинки сделать прелоадер для мобильного приложения

[image]

чтобы она вращалась, когда ее показывают, этот код работает, только по какому нибудь событию, например :hover

```
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transition-duration:1000ms;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
```

Вопрос: как заставить картинку крутиться циклически и как сделать, чтобы анимация происходила сразу в момент показывания дива с этим изображением используя только цсс3.

Comment: решение нашел здесь http://deer.org.ua/2012/02/24/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Оставлю ка я это здесь, для наглядности решения

```
.loader{
    -webkit-animation: preloader 1.5s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: preloader 1.5s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: preloader 1.5s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: preloader 1.5s infinite linear;
    animation: preloader 1.5s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes preloader {
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes preloader {
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes preloader {
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes preloader {
    to { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes preloader {
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Chrome 2+, Safari 4+, Firefox 5+, IE10 PP3, iOS Safari 3.2+, Android 2.1+.

```
<img class="loader" src="spin.png">
```

Есть ещё [такое](http://codepen.io/jabranr/pen/GLFjv), без картинок.